# Installing pcl_ros from binaries does not install executables in /opt/ros/lib

Tags: ros2, pcl-ros, ros-iron, binaries

I wanted to experiment with point cloud filters from `pcl_ros` in my ROS2 project. Hence, I have added `pcl_ros` as an `<exec_depend>` in my `package.xml` and I can see `pcl_ros` folder in `/opt/ros/iron/share` (after installing deps through `rosdep`). Just to confirm, I also did a `apt install ros-iron-pcl-ros` and saw that the package was already installed (as expected).

However, when I create an xml launch file to start the filter nodes, I see the following error:

> package 'pcl_ros' found at '/opt/ros/iron', but libexec directory '/opt/ros/iron/lib/pcl_ros' does not exist

This is how my xml launch file looks like:

```
<launch>
    <node name="basic_filter" pkg="pcl_ros" exec="filter_passthrough_node" output="log">
        <remap from="input" to="my_pointcloud" />
        <remap from="output" to="my_filtered_pointcloud" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

I created the launch file based on the package name as [mentioned here](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/0722a701d4ea47dc0b5bb5bebd67179b5b341135/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt#L2) and the executable name [mentioned here](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/0722a701d4ea47dc0b5bb5bebd67179b5b341135/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt#L102).

There is indeed no `pcl_ros` folder in `/opt/ros/iron/lib` as seen in the error message. But I was expecting the binary install would also install the executables.

Then, I pulled `pcl_ros` from source (`ros2` branch). It compiled successfully and the launch file starts the passthrough filter with:

> [INFO] [filter_passthrough_node-1]: process started with pid [83765]

This prompted me to check the [release tag used for the binaries](https://index.ros.org/p/pcl_ros/github-ros-perception-perception_pcl/) and it turns out that the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/blob/2.4.1/pcl_ros/CMakeLists.txt) in the release binaries doesn't have rules to install the filter targets.

Further the [commit history](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/commit/de09161924ae8c04499610ed7d47fc1e8f7af9cb://) shows that the necessary rules to install the filter targets were already done about a year ago (well before the latest release date) on the ROS package index.

Hence, I was wondering, if support for these filters is being phased out and hence recent releases don't use the updated `CMakeLists.txt`. Should I use a different package?

Kindly let me know if further information is necessary.

System: Ubuntu 22.04

ROS Distro: Iron Irwini

Comment: It seems there is a [tracking issue][1] related to this on the code repo.


  [1]: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/439